# Auto Etiquetador de zonas de una señal en python

Tags: python

Quería presentar un problema que quiero resolver con python y que no logro alcanzar la mejor solución. Resulta que tengo una señal muy larga, de aproximadamente 30 minutos, sampleada con una frecuencia de 2KHz, por lo que tengo unas 3 600 000 samples. Esta señal tiene diferentes zonas, en concreto 3, y quiero hacer un algoritmo para poder etiquetar automáticamente estas zonas dentro de la señal.

**Mi idea es poder colorear el fondo de la gráfica de una zona hasta su transición a la siguiente zona**. Estas etiquetas se presentan periódicamente en la señal por lo que tengo que poder pintar en el gráfico de forma repetitiva. Para concretar más, ¿Hay alguna forma de pintar el fondo de un plot para establecer etiquetas? Si no, ¿Recomendáis algún método visual de etiquetado de señales?

[image: Señal]

Esta es la señal que quiero llegar a etiquetar.

¿Recomendáis alguna herramienta, alguna idea o algo que pueda enfocar los primeros pasos? El resultado que quiero es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias a todos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: No me queda del todo claro qué preguntas exactamente ¿quieres simplemente pintar esas bandas encima de la señal (o más bien debajo), pero tienes ya en algunas variables dónde empieza y acaba cada zona? ¿O necesitas también un algoritmo que identifique dónde acaba una zona y empieza la siguiente? ¿Cuál sería en este caso el criterio en el cual basar esa decisión?

Comment: El método de etiquetado lo estoy haciendo por ahora totalmente matemático y voy a barajar opciones de algún algoritmo de clasificación. La pregunta va más por cómo puedo etiquetar visualmente en una gráfica las secciones de la señal, colorear el plot basicamente.

Comment: ¿Cual es la diferencia entre la zona A y B? A mi me parece que B es simplemente una continuación de A.

Comment: Tiene sus caracteristicas para identificarla pero igual en la tercera zona  B puedes ver cómo se identifica mejor est patron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limito la respuesta al problema de cómo añadir las franjas de colores etiquetadas debajo del plot, y no a cómo se encuentran las coordenadas de origen y fin de esas franjas.

Empecemos por crear algunos datos al azar que se parezcan vagamente a tu figura:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import randint

size=3700

data = np.random.randint(-100, 101, size=size)
for i in range(50):
  data[randint(0,size)] = randint(-700, 700)
plt.plot(data)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para dibujar una zona en el fondo tienes la función `ax.axvspan()`, y para escribir un texto como "A", "B", etc con el que etiquetar la región se puede usar `ax.annotate()`. Así que preparo una función que haga esto para que sea más cómodo usarla luego:

```
def etiquetar_region(ax, inicio, fin, etiqueta, color):
  ax.axvspan(inicio, fin, facecolor=color, edgecolor="black", alpha=0.2)
  y = ax.get_ybound()[1] * 0.98
  ax.annotate(etiqueta, xy=(inicio, y),
              verticalalignment="top")
```

La coordenada `x` en la que colocar el texto la hago igual al inicio de la región que se está etiquetando. La coordenada `y` donde colocar el texto la hago igual a "un poquito menos" (de ahí el 0.98) que el valor de `y` más alto en la gráfica (lo que se obtiene con `ax.get_ybound()`.

### Ejemplo de uso

Si tenemos una lista con las regiones a etiquetar (cada una define su x de inicio y fin, su etiqueta y el color) como la siguiente:

```
regiones = [
    (300, 1500, "A", "green"),
    (1500, 2000, "B", "yellow"),
    (2000, 2200, "C", "red")
]
```

Podemos hacer un bucle para pintar todas esas regiones:

```
plt.plot(data)
ax = plt.gca()

for inicio, fin, nombre, color in regiones:
  etiquetar_region(ax, inicio, fin, nombre, color)
```

Con el siguiente resultado:

[image: Resultado]

### Ampliación

Si prefieres que las zonas coloreadas vayan *encima* del plot en vez de debajo (para que así también coloreen levemente la zona azul), basta añadir `zorder=2.5` a los parámetros de `ax.axvspan()`.

De paso lo modifico también para que las etiquetas salgan centradas horizontalmente en las regiones, para que veas cómo podría hacerse:

```
def etiquetar_region(ax, inicio, fin, etiqueta, color):
  ax.axvspan(inicio, fin, facecolor=color, edgecolor="black", alpha=0.2, zorder=2.5)
  x = (inicio+fin)/2
  y = ax.get_ybound()[1] * 0.95
  ax.annotate(etiqueta, xy=(x, y),
              verticalalignment="top",
              horizontalalignment="center")
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

[image: REgiones pintadas encima]

Comment: Oh, perfecto. Esto es genial. Con esta función podré utilizar el output de mi función de clasificación para colorear automáticamente sobre la señal. Me será de gran utilidad. Es una maravilla ver tanta ayuda y tan buena por el foro. Muchas gracias!